# error message ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'

Tags: solidity, remix

I have this error but I do not know what is wrong?

```
browser/arry.sol:6:58: ParserError: Expected ',' but got 'memory'
    function addScore(unit24 s) public returens(unit24 []memory){
                                                         ^----^
```

**this is my code**

```
pragma solidity^0.5.0;

contract Score {
    unit24[]score;

    function addScore(unit24 s) public returens(unit24 []memory){
        score.push(s);
        return score;
    }

    function getLength()view public returens(unit){
        return score.length;
    }

    function clearArray() public returens(unit24 [] memory){
        delete score;
        return score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled `uint` (you wrote `unit`) and `returns` (you wrote `returens`). Code with those misspellings corrected compiles fine:

```
pragma solidity^0.5.0;

contract Score {

    uint24[] score;

    function addScore(uint24 s) public returns (uint24[] memory) {
        score.push(s);
        return score;
    }

    function getLength() view public returns (uint) {
        return score.length;
    }

    function clearArray() public returns (uint24[] memory) {
        delete score;
        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: I  misspelled , you are right,  thank you